# How can I put my curvilinear coordinate data on a map projection?

Tags: python, interpolation, netcdf

I'm working with NetCDF files from NCAR and I'm trying to plot sea-ice thickness. This variable is on a curvilinear (TLAT,TLON) grid. What is the best way to plot this data on a map projection? Do I need to re-grid it to a regular grid or is there a way to plot it directly? I'm fairly new to Python so any help would be appreciated. Please let me know if you need any more information. Thank you!

I've tried libraries like iris, scipy, and basemap, but I couldn't really get a clear explanation on how to implement them for my case.

Comment: The best way is always to obtain from the source data a parametric description (e.g. PROJ4 code) of the projection. If this is not present, it means the data was not created according to the CF-Conventions. In any case iirc `xarray` can plot curvilinear grids: https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/plotting.html#multidimensional-coordinates

Comment: Inside python, you can also use https://xesmf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Curvilinear_grid.html to regrid to the grid of your choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure you can already use methods like `contour`, `contourf`, `pcolormesh` from Python's `matplotlib` without re-gridding the data. The same methods work for `Basemap`.